# Enterprise library 6.0 configuration editor for Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, enterprise-library, .net-4.6

For our new project(Using Visual Studio 2017 and .net Framework 4.6), a decision has been taken to use Enterprise Library 6.0 for Logging, Exception Handling and DB access. I have a lot of resources/materials available on Internet on how to use it. My questions are,

1. I couldn't find any Enterprise Library configuration console available for visual studio 2017. Is there any standalone editor available for EL6.0?
2. if it's available where to download it?
3. If there is no extension(for vs2017)/standalone editor available, then how can I configure it manually? Any documentation available to state the properties to be set clearly?
4. Will EL6.0 supports .net framework 4.6 and work flawlessly?

Please help me to find it out and decide.